# Pass string[] object from client to service wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7.1

**IService1.cs**

```
    [OperationContract]
    string SendMessage(string[] contact, string message,CookieContainer con);
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
  string SendMessage(string[] contact, string message,CookieContainer con);
  {
   .... ..... 
   .... 
   ... code
  }
```

Client Side

```
string[] contact;
svc.SendMessageCompleted += new EventHandler<SendMessageCompletedEventArgs>(svc_Send_Sms);
svc.SendMessageAsync(contact, txtsms.Text,con);
```

this gives error

> The best overloaded method match for 'SmsApplication.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.SendMessageAsync(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection, string, System.Net.CookieContainer)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this solution should work.
Right click on the service reference
Choose the configure service reference option
Under the Data Type section change the Collection type from Array to the type you want in the drop down menu.

Comment: I change it to System.Array and run application it gives error like this **"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:con. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 435. 'EndElement' 'con' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element 'm_count'.'.  Please see InnerException for "**

Comment: I think you need to change it from System.Array to 
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Comment: Then it gives error on **contact** that I mention in question

Comment: Are you using System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection anywhere in your code?

Comment: I pass cookiecontainer object i.e. **con**

Comment: What method is `SendMessageAsync`? I don't see it defined in the contract. Try `SendMessage` instead

Comment: This method is in service. I call it from client i.e. from windows phone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16616/discussion-between-lews-therin-and-ajay)